# Receiving data from another class and sending via mail - Android

Tags: java, android, email

I'm have simple code and I need to send data downloaded from openweathermap via mail.

Barometr.java:

```
public void getPressure(JSONObjesc jObject){
    try{
        JSONObject cis = jObject.getJSONObject("main");
        pressure = cis.getInt("pressure");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("Barometr", "Error");
    }
}
```

BarometrActivity (main class):

```
private void showMailDialog(){
    AlertDialog.Builder sendmail = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    sendmail.setTitle("Send mail to:");
    final EditText adress = new EditText(this);
    adress.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    sendmail.setView(adress);
    sendmail.setPositiveButton("Send", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent mail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            mail.setType("text/plain");
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {adress.getText().toString()});
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Pressure");
            mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sample");
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mail, "Send mail"));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(BarometrActivity.this, "Missing app.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
    sendmail.show();
}
```

I want to put pressure information with sample descripstion in the e-mail.

Can you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Where is the code you tried for sending an email? check this anyways. http://superuser.com/questions/606258/can-i-programmatically-send-email-using-my-gmail-account

Comment: I haven't code yet, cuz I don't know how to do this :/ 
I want put this info here: mail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sample");